# Assign a variable in Postgres stored procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to assign a value of `interval` type to a variable called `frequency_to_add` in my stored procedure based on a condition of if the frequency is greater than 1200000 or less than 1200000. Depending on the frequency, the variable will be different, so I can use that variable throughout the procedure. Currently I have the following, but it is complaining about about syntax error at  `WHEN (dpl.frequency < '1200000')` what is the wrong with this? (I have not replaced the code with the created variable in the code below yet)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mo_show_slow_network()

    RETURNS TABLE(
        id            BIGINT,
        time_late_by    DOUBLE PRECISION
        )
AS
$$
DECLARE
    frequency_to_add interval; 
BEGIN
    CASE WHEN (dpl.frequency > '1200000')
            THEN frequency_to_add = 20 * interval '1 minute'
         WHEN (dpl.frequency < '1200000')
            THEN frequency_to_add = dpl.frequency * interval '1 milliseconds'

RETURN QUERY
    SELECT 
    dpl.dp_id AS dp_id,
    CASE 
         WHEN (dpl.frequency > '1200000')
            THEN EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (current_timestamp - dpl.date_created) + 20 * interval '1 minute') 
         WHEN(dpl.frequency < '1200000')
            THEN EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (current_timestamp - dpl.date_created) + dpl.frequency * interval '1 milliseconds')
        ELSE NULL
    END AS time_late_by

FROM -- rest of code...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the variable to the result of the `CASE` expression. You can't do an assignment inside the case:

```
frequency_to_add := CASE WHEN (dpl.frequency > '1200000')
                       THEN 20 * interval '1 minute'
                    WHEN (dpl.frequency < '1200000')
                       THEN dpl.frequency * interval '1 milliseconds'
                    end;
```

But that still won't work, because the assignment does not have access to the alias `dbl` which you define *after* the `case` statement.

So you can not actually do what you want like that. You will need to keep the `case` statement in the `select` as it is.

Comment: I will be using that variable at the two EXTRACT statements

Comment: But you have no access to `dbl` at that point in the code. So you can't assign the variable in the first place.

Comment: Gotcha, tested it and realized it